# Rails + JRuby: I'm getting a JDBC error while rendering the default app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jdbc, jruby

I'm trying to make Rails work under a JRuby environment. I got everything working; no installation errors.

I installed Rails using `jruby -S gem install rails`, then I created a test app using both `jruby -S rails new webtest` and `rails -S new webtest` (second attempt). Both commands deploy the complete app directory with no errors.

Now, I haven't changed anything at all and I'm now just trying to see if the defaults work before I try anything else, so I `cd webtest` and run `jruby -S rails server -b x.xx.xx.xx` (second attempt: `rails server -b x.xx.xx.xx`) where the x's represent the server ip address in the internal network. The service is started and outputs the app URL, PID etc. I'm binding to the ip address because I need to access the app from another machine since the server itself is console only (if I leave the default bind [i.e. localhost], the app is unreachable for some reason).

But when I try to open the app (accessing from another machine) using `http://x.xx.xx.xx:3000` I get the a Rails exception page with the header **ActiveRecord::JDBCError** and the following stacktrace. I tried to figure out what's wrong but, as you can see, the trace doesn't show any specific error message besides the trace.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

```
>jruby -S rails server -b x.xx.xx.xx
NOTE: ActiveRecord 4.2 is not (yet) fully supported by AR-JDBC, please help us finish 4.2 support - check http://bit.ly/jruby-42 for starters
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://x.xx.xx.xx:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-02-27 14:28:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-02-27 14:28:00] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-12-06) [java]
[2015-02-27 14:28:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=25886932 port=3000
```

Then while trying to access the app URL from another machine:

```
arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:453:in `init_connection'
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.14) lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:15:in `initialize'
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.14) lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:68:in `initialize'
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.14) lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:12:in `jdbc_connection'
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.14) lib/arjdbc/sqlite3/connection_methods.rb:24:in `sqlite3_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `checkout'
/home/srpec/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `connection'
/home/srpec/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:384:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:371:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:738:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/home/srpec/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/srpec/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/srpec/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/server.rb:191:in `start_thread'
```

Environment information:

```
>rails -v
Rails 4.2.0

>jruby -v
jruby 1.7.9 (1.9.3p392) 2013-12-06 87b108a on IBM J9 VM pap3270_27sr2-20141101_01 (SR2) [AIX-ppc]

>jgem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.0)
actionpack (4.2.0)
actionview (4.2.0)
activejob (4.2.0)
activemodel (4.2.0)
activerecord (4.2.0)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.14)
activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.3.14)
activesupport (4.2.0)
arel (6.0.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.8.3)
coffee-rails (4.1.0)
coffee-script (2.3.0)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.3.0)
globalid (0.3.3)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
jbuilder (2.2.8)
jdbc-sqlite3 (3.8.7)
jquery-rails (4.0.3)
json (1.8.2 java)
loofah (2.0.1)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.4.3)
minitest (5.5.1)
multi_json (1.10.1)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2 java)
rack (1.6.0)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.0)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.5)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.1)
railties (4.2.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
sass (3.4.13)
sass-rails (5.0.1)
sdoc (0.4.1)
sprockets (2.12.3)
sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
therubyrhino (2.0.4)
therubyrhino_jar (1.7.4)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4 java)
tilt (1.4.1)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
tzinfo-data (1.2015.1)
uglifier (2.7.0)
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with this note in the console from when you ran `rails server`?
`NOTE: ActiveRecord 4.2 is not (yet) fully supported by AR-JDBC, please help us finish 4.2 support - check http://bit.ly/jruby-42 for starters`

Comment: ... and you're also on some older JRuby 1.7.x with IBM Java ... I would probably try to upgrade JRuby and downgrade Rails ... also isn't there no message with the exception?

Comment: The JRuby version I'm using is close to the latest. Actually, 1.7.9 was the latest version until about 2 months ago when I downloaded it (current is 1.7.19). As for ActiveRecord, it works fine for me under this same installation/environment because I have a non-rails application that makes use of the API. in summary, everything works fine in this JRuby environment so I really think it's something with my Rails installation. I'll try to dig more into the configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @alexcavalli and kares. I downgraded Rails and ActiveRecord to 4.1.8 to avoid issues with the missing support for AR-JDBC. That got rid of the warning message. I still couldn't get SQLite3 to work, unfortunately. After I changed the configuration to use my DB2 connection though, Rails worked perfectly fine. Therefore, it's probably some problem with the SQLite3 adapter. Also, I forgot to mention that I'm running Rails on a AIX server which also caused another issue with TZInfo. To fix this I installed and added the tzinfo and tzinfo-data gems to the Gemfile.